# Scrapy, could not get the next page

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm working on Google search results crawling through this link.

[https://www.google.com/search?q=telsa+"model3"+intext:model3&hl=en&rlz](https://www.google.com/search?q=telsa+%22model3%22+intext:model3&hl=en&rlz)

I have disabled Javascript in the Chrome Browser and obtained the xpath value for Next.
[image]

xpath -> //*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvnHz.png)/div/div/a

Here is my code

```
import scrapy
from ..items import GooglescrapyItem
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs


 class GoogleBotsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'GoogleScrapyBot'
    allowed_domains = ['google.com']

    start_urls = [f'https://www.google.com/search?q=telsa+"model3"+intext:model3&hl=en&rlz']

    def parse(self, response):

       titles = response.xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div/div/div/a/h3/div//text()').extract()
       links = response.xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div/div/div/a/@href').extract()
       next_page = response.xpath('//*[@id="main"]/footer/div/div/div/a/@href').extract()
       items = []

       for idx in range(len(titles)):
          item = GooglescrapyItem()
          item['title'] = titles[idx]
          parsed_url = urlparse(links[idx])
          query_params = parse_qs(parsed_url.query)
          item['link'] = query_params["q"][0]
          items.append(item)

       if next_page:
          next_href = next_page[0]
          next_page_url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=telsa+"model3"+intext:model3&hl=en&rlz' + next_href
          request = scrapy.Request(url=next_page_url)
          yield request

    return items
```

output

DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET [https://www.google.com/search?q=telsa+%22model3%22+intext:model3&hl=en&rlz>](https://www.google.com/search?q=telsa+%22model3%22+intext:model3&hl=en&rlz%3E) (referer: None)

DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET [https://www.google.com/search?q=telsa+%22model3%22+intext:model3&hl=en&rlz/search?q=telsa+%22model3%22+intext:model3&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&ei=LMrhYP3IOY6v0PEPmKGNoAg&start=10&sa=N>](https://www.google.com/search?q=telsa+%22model3%22+intext:model3&hl=en&rlz/search?q=telsa+%22model3%22+intext:model3&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&ei=LMrhYP3IOY6v0PEPmKGNoAg&start=10&sa=N%3E) (referer: https://www.google.com/search?q=telsa+%22model3%22+intext:model3&hl=en&rlz)

DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET [https://www.google.com/search?q=telsa+%22model3%22+intext:model3&hl=en&rlz/search?q=telsa+%22model3%22+intext:model3&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&ei=LsrhYIf-AdSTr7wPtt-LyA4&start=0&sa=N>](https://www.google.com/search?q=telsa+%22model3%22+intext:model3&hl=en&rlz/search?q=telsa+%22model3%22+intext:model3&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&ei=LsrhYIf-AdSTr7wPtt-LyA4&start=0&sa=N%3E) (referer: https://www.google.com/search?q=telsa+%22model3%22+intext:model3&hl=en&rlz/search?q=telsa+%22model3%22+intext:model3&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&ei=LMrhYP3IOY6v0PEPmKGNoAg&start=10&sa=N)

DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET [https://www.google.com/search?q=telsa+%22model3%22+intext:model3&hl=en&rlz/search?q=telsa+%22model3%22+intext:model3&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&ei=L8rhYJCNCI7_0gSA5qKAAg&start=10&sa=N>](https://www.google.com/search?q=telsa+%22model3%22+intext:model3&hl=en&rlz/search?q=telsa+%22model3%22+intext:model3&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&ei=L8rhYJCNCI7_0gSA5qKAAg&start=10&sa=N%3E) (referer: https://www.google.com/search?q=telsa+%22model3%22+intext:model3&hl=en&rlz/search?q=telsa+%22model3%22+intext:model3&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&ei=LsrhYIf-AdSTr7wPtt-LyA4&start=0&sa=N)

DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET [https://www.google.com/search?q=telsa+%22model3%22+intext:model3&hl=en&rlz/search?q=telsa+%22model3%22+intext:model3&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&ei=MMrhYOLRHeLFmAX2w4ioBA&start=0&sa=N>](https://www.google.com/search?q=telsa+%22model3%22+intext:model3&hl=en&rlz/search?q=telsa+%22model3%22+intext:model3&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&ei=MMrhYOLRHeLFmAX2w4ioBA&start=0&sa=N%3E) (referer: https://www.google.com/search?q=telsa+%22model3%22+intext:model3&hl=en&rlz/search?q=telsa+%22model3%22+intext:model3&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&ei=L8rhYJCNCI7_0gSA5qKAAg&start=10&sa=N)

...Skip

Question

Google Search Pages will increase by 10 steps, such as &start=0 &start=10 &start=20 &start=30.
However, my code repeats &start=0 and &start=10 and does not move to &start=20

Could you please go over my code?

Answer (score 0):

Try `nextPage = response.xpath('//td[@role="heading"]/a/@href').get()`

Comment: Thank you. I just replace next_page with your suggestion like this... next_page = response.xpath('//td[@role="heading"]/a/@href').get() print('next_page ->', next_page) if next_page:.... However, there is nothing next_page (next_page -> None).